# lvmetad error when I turn the computer on or off

Tags: boot, shutdown, lvm

I am using Lubuntu 17.10 and every time I start the computer, after Lubuntu boots it shows this error:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.

/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: clean, 239554/9674752 files, 19597960/38680576 blocks
```

When I turn off the computer the same error appears and after that it shows a blue screen and gets stuck in this position (doesn't turn off).

Comment: I, too, am getting the same message.  However, my machine proceeds to boot... but, I remain skeptical.  I receive several error-reporting opps per session.  I am interested how I might remove the warning...?

Ubuntu 17.10 here as well.